# How can I sign in with a different account?

Tags: discussion

I can't sign in with a different account (with stackexchange). Somebody before me used my computer to sign in to their account (with stackexchange)...and now whenver I try to log out and then log in with my own account, it doesn't work. I click log out and then try to sign in with my own account but it automatically opens up the other person's account. So how is it possible to change this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: i) purge the browsing history, ii) clean the cache and temporary file, and iii) clear form auto-fill data.

Comment: Yes @Penguin_Knight this should be good enough to give as answer. Also see this question, not quite the same, but advice transfers, http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1513/1036.

Comment: Have you signed *them* out of whatever service they use to log into SE? For example, if they log into SE with Google, have you logged them out of Google?